# Can't view Review Apps despite View permission being granted

Tags: heroku, heroku-review-app

Collaborators with view access cannot open review apps created through a GitHub Pull Request. I'm an Admin at our corporate Heroku account and can't view apps either. It was working fine until last Friday it seems. I couldn't see any change in permissions.

App permissions:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
George